# Problem of the Google play store

Tags: google-play-store

As soon as I get into Google Play store and search for an app, it automatically comes to the home screen of the Android device and a notification appears asking whether you want to close the app or open it once again.Will this problem will be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This could just be that you are running out of RAM. There is more information on this [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/128165/253787), if you need it.